# Are these posts inadequate and need to be replaced?

Tags: basement, structural, column

My house is almost 100 years old and the previous owner did some renovations about 15 years ago without permits. I'm concerned the beams in the basement are insufficiently supported. There's a main carrying beam running most of the length of the house with a pair of cross beams that it intersects with at the back. Around that intersection appears to be supported with 4x4 posts as opposed to footed steel columns like those under the main beam at the middle and front of the house.

There are no visible signs of sagging; everything in the kitchen and dining room upstairs is square and as level as you can expect in an old house. But I want to get ahead of any serious issues forming. We do plan to renovate the basement which will be the opportune time to shore things up properly. But budget-wise that's at least 5 years away.

So what is the best course in the mean time? Again, nothing appears to be wrong but, in addition to not being code, I don't like so much weight being supported by 4x4 posts. Would adding/swapping in a few adjustable steel jack posts be sufficient or is more necessary in the short term? Obviously the final word would come from an engineer but I'm trying to get some input before deciding to shell out money for that when I plan to do it a few years from now for the bigger project.

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately this question is unanswerable with what you've told us. Any post/beam calculation needs span and load info. If those 4x4s are every six feet and resting on footings, for hypothetical example, there's no issue. Please revise to add detail.

Comment: 4x4s are quite strong, almost equal to the steel posts.  As long as they are on good footings it should not be a problem.  An addition added to my house in the 90s only has 4x4s supporting the beam(only a 3 foot crawlspace).  Does not hurt to have a structural engineer check it out for you, for your peace of mind.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. For additional info, the cross beams span about 20 feet. Each has a single 4x4 about at about 8' from the one wall. Harder to tell all what's under the main beam because there's a wall under it, but there are at least 2 4x4s about 6' apart, hopefully more behind that wall. They do not appear properly footed.

Comment: Get a local structural engineer in to look at the house. He'll tell you about anything that needs to be addressed _NOW_, and anything that can be put off for a couple of years.

Comment: You can not tell from looking the footing is normally below the slab, on homes this old some footings were brick and when a slab was poured later no permits were needed, if no structural changes were made no permits are usually needed. The beams can be clear span if thick enough that is wall to wall with no supports between so as Isherwood said there is not enough info.